# Unable connect to page. Browserstack

Tags: angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing, browserstack, gulp-protractor

I use protractor with Browserstack.exe for e2e (UI) testing.

I have to check authorization proccess. It goes in this way:

1. go to domain/#login
2. redirect to auth0.com to get authorized (hosted auth0 authorization)
3. enter credentials
4. redirect to my angular client with finished authentification.

I read that for testing separate login page we have to use 
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

Sometimes it works, some - not. 
I don't understand why and what depends on this.

I have this error while run protractor:
Expected 'http://localhost:8001/app/#/login' to contain 'domen.auth0.com'.

and this screen:
[image: browserstack screenshot]

my code :

```
describe('[domain.reports]', function () {

    beforeAll(function() {
        // it makes protractor not wait for Angular promises
        // for testing separate login page.
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    });

    beforeEach(function () {
        browser.wait(browser.get('#/login'), 5000);
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('domain.auth0.com');
    });

    it('should automatically redirect to /samples when location hash/fragment is empty', function () {

        var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        var el = element(by.css('.auth0-lock-submit'));
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(el), 10000);
        protractor.loginHelpers.loginToPage('test_customer@gmail.com', 'Qazxsw123456');
        protractor.waitHelpers.waitForUrlToBeChanged("/samples");

        //browser.wait(browser.get('#/samples'), 5000);
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch("/samples");
        browser.get('#/api');
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).not.toContain("/api");
    });
});
```

It works at another scenarious...

Thank you in advise for any thoughts!

Comment: Are the tests passing locally (without browserstack)? Can you also share the entire command are you using to start Browserstack.exe? Also, based on your description, should the get command be browser.get('/#/login'); OR browser.get('#/login')?